# Why am I not being able to add basic Authorization in SOAP header?

Tags: c#, soap, basic-authentication

myAPI is the name of a web service reference I added to my project and I am trying to send Basic Authorization into the header of the SOAP request using C# but it’s not happening no matter what method I try.

I read a lot online and ended up with the following ways but none seem to work with mine.

**What I've tried:**

Method 1: *no error but does nothing*

```
  NetworkCredential netCredential = new NetworkCredential("un", "pw");
  Uri uri = new Uri(resol.Url);
  ICredentials credentials = netCredential.GetCredential(uri, "Basic");
  myAPI.Credentials = credentials;
  myAPI.PreAuthenticate = true;
```

Method 2: *(FYI ResolvingBinding (below) basically consists of all my method which comes from the service reference myAPI) but the problem is : "client" does not have any definition for InnerChannel and ClientCredential so this method fails too*

```
myAPI.ResolvingBinding client = new myAPI.ResolvingBinding();
using (OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))
{
    var httpRequestProperty = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
    httpRequestProperty.Headers[System.Net.HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Basic " +
                 Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName + ":" +
                 client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password));
    OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = httpRequestProperty;

    client.DoSomething();
}
```

My ultimate end goal is to encode username:password into base 64 which I tried in the second example.
How do I go about resolving this? Please feel free to add a comment/leave a suggestion or point out mistakes I might've overlooked.

Answer (score 1):

This code should add your basic authentication to your header

```
var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(<userId> + ":" +<pw>);
string val = System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
string textValue = "Basic " + val;
httpRequestProperty.Headers.Add("Authorization", textValue);
```

Comment: Tried this too. Shows no error but can't seem to understand why there is still no header in the req.

Comment: Do you have fiddler so you can capture and post the request that is being sent?

Comment: it has everything except the header.

POST /easws/api/soap/ResolvingPort HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 4.0.30319.42000)
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: "http://aaa.bbb.com/xyz/"
Host: hello.world.com:12345
Content-Length: 541
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: close